# How to Image file and Audio file merge in flutter ?same as in Instagram Story

Tags: flutter

How to Image file and Audio file merge in flutter? same as in Instagram Story and i have tried in flutter_ffmpeg plugin i not getting propare solution

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do here is that you should play audio only when user tap on that image and stop playing it when the user go back (like instagram). so one simple solution is that you can wrap that image in a gesturehandler widget with an ontap function and when that is triggered, inside it you call a function that plays that specific sound you want for that image.

Comment: That is not possible because  I will create one file and uploading on server